# Atmega16U4 (Hardware USB) does not show up as DFU device on device manager

Tags: avr, atmega, atmel, usb-device, atmega32u4

I am trying to get the Atmega16U4 to show up in windows device manager. Right now, when I connect the atmega16U4 through USB to the computer it does not do anything (does not even play the USB connection sound). I have wired it up following [this guide for a similar chip](http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/863.14/people/andrew_mao/week11/).

I have connected a 16Mhz crystal oscillator with 2 - 20pF capacitors provided with the crystal. The USB D+ and D- lines use 22 Ohm resistors as recommended by the datasheet. VBUS on the USB is connected to VBUS on the Atmega16U4. Power to the USB module is connected (UVCC and UGND are connected to 5V and GND).

Is there anything I'm missing here? Or could it be that my chip is not entering DFU bootloader? (the datasheet says that the Atmega16U4 comes with the DFU bootloader factory programmed)

Things I did before this was to change the fuses - CLKDIV8 fuse disabled (enabled by default). To change this fuse I had to first do a Erase Chip operation. I read that the Erase chip option does not erase the bootloader, was I wrong with this assumption? If yes, then what can I do to get the bootloader back on?

[Here's the datasheet for the Atmega16U4](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-7766-8-bit-avr-atmega16u4-32u4_datasheet.pdf)

Any help would be extremely useful to me right now.

EDIT: Attached schematic. This version of the schematic does not include the !HWB connected to ground but I have connected it on hardware. (pin 33 to ground)

[image: Atmega16U4 USB schematic]

Thanks in advance,
Harid.

Comment: Have you pulled the boot pin (`PE2/!HWB`) low?

Comment: Yes, I tied it low using a jumper and !RESET is tied high through a 10K resistor.

Comment: Could you post a photo of your circuit (both schematic and hardware)

Comment: I have attached the schematic as you requested, but the schematic does not include the !HWB pin going to ground, I have that connected on hardware. Unfortunately, I can't post  pictures of hardware as the hardware is remote with my client :(

Comment: Sorry Tom, I forgot to attach my image in my previous edit. I have updated it with the attachment.

Comment: Which exact part did you order? The one with bootloader preinstalled, or without it? And if it was with the bootloader, did you order it with the internal RC oscillator fuse, or the external crystal fuse? It should work with the external 16 MHz crystal, why change the fuse? Erasing the MCU via DFU should not erase the bootloader, but via standard ISP it erases everything, including the bootloader. If you did erase it via ISP, then you can reprogram the bootloader and fuses via ISP as well.

Comment: I erased it using the ICE, so it erased the boot loader as well. I reprogrammed the bootloader using the hex file from microship's website and it worked! I tried this before as well but it turns out I had loose wires on my USB breakout board the last time I tried.

Comment: Unfortunately the ATmega (vs Xmega) ISP does not offer anything less than a total erase.  Partial erase is only possibly when done by the bootloader running on the chip itself, externally performed erase always wipes out everything.  And it seems this family has no "ROM" or permanent factory locked flash sectors.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for the information Chris. Unfortunately I had to find out the hard way! 